# How I play with device game

Tags: android, kotlin

I have application game that contains 2 player. I want set the game to play with device when I play, I go first and device doesn't click after I click. Then the other player chose a random button, and I want when I play they play after me don't wait after click then device click

```
fun action(optionNumber: Int, btnselected: Button) {



    if (playingplayer == PLAYINGPLAYER.FIRST_PLAYER) {

        btnselected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_game_green)
        buttonClickes1Player.add(optionNumber)
        btnselected.isEnabled = false
        playingplayer = PLAYINGPLAYER.SECOND_PLAYER

    } else if (playingplayer == PLAYINGPLAYER.SECOND_PLAYER) {

        var noSelectedButton: ArrayList<Int> = ArrayList()

        for (buttonNumber in 1..10){
            if (!(buttonClickes1Player.contains(buttonNumber))){
                noSelectedButton.add(buttonNumber)
            }
        }

        try {

            var randomNumber = (Math.random() * noSelectedButton.size).toInt()
            var buttonNumber = noSelectedButton[randomNumber]

            when(buttonNumber){
                1 -> btnselected = btn1
                2 -> btnselected = btn2
                3 -> btnselected = btn3
                4 -> btnselected = btn4
                5 -> btnselected = btn5
                6 -> btnselected = btn6
                7 -> btnselected = btn7
                8 -> btnselected = btn8
                9 -> btnselected = btn9
                10 -> btnselected = btn10
            }

            btnselected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_game_red)
            buttonClickes1Player.add(optionNumber)
            btnselected.isEnabled = false
            playingplayer = PLAYINGPLAYER.FIRST_PLAYER

        }catch (e: Exception){
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    imagebtnState()
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What does the loop look like that calls `action`?

Comment: i want when i play device play after me Automatically

Comment: i have 2 player every time one player click button when i set this code to play whit device i'm player 1 i click first but device player he don't clickafter i click any button then he click randomly , know the player 1 must i click but device is player 2 don't click, i want when i play device play Automatically after me

Comment: i hope you understand what i want say